# Allow user to purchase Stripe SKU in local currency

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a Stripe SKU with a `currency` of `usd` and a `price` of `12000`.

I want to let my customer purchase this SKU using Euros (i.e., spending about €85).

To do this I first create a Stripe customer using Stripe Elements and then I create a Stripe order like this:

```
Stripe::Order.create({
  currency: 'eur',
  customer: stripe_customer_id,
  items: [
    {
      type: 'sku',
      currency: 'eur',
      parent: stripe_sku_id,
      quantity: 1,
      amount: 12000
    }
  ],
})
```

But when I do this I get this exception:

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError: Order item currency usd does not match order currency eur.
```

I think this is because the OrderItem takes its currency from the SKU (instead of the `currency` attribute) and the SKU is in USD.

How can I enable the user to make this purchase?

Comment: You would need to create an SKU with the correct currency, or update the existing one. The order needs to have the same currency as the contained items. Another approach would be to create the order in `usd` to present in that currency to the customer, but then they would potentially have to pay the conversion costs.

Comment: @karllekko Stripe will not allow me to create two different SKUs that are the same in every way except for the currency. Currently I use SKUs for sizes and so if I were to use your approach instead of having an "XL" SKU I'd need to have an "USD-XL" and an "EUR-XL" which seems pretty hack-y but maybe it's the only way?

Comment: Also creating separate SKUs for each currency would make it impossible to track inventory which is one of the huge reasons to use SKUs in the first place. Surely there must be a better way to do this! SKUs represent physical items in a warehouse somewhere—those items might have a size, color, etc, but *currency* is not a property of the thing in the warehouse and so it should not be a property of the associated SKU...

Comment: I fully agree and suppose its not a priority for stripe, as they are a US company and think they rule the world, that everyone use $$ and the earth is flat ;)